# Как в условии if обозначить нажатие на какой либо элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно в условие `if` вписать событие клика на элемент. Например у меня 3 кнопки в блочном элементе, что нужно написать в скобках вместо `...`, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 2, срабатывала консоль

```
if (...) {
    console.log(123);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.block').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const button = e.target.closest('.block__button');

  if (!button) return;

  if (button.getAttribute('data-button') === '2') {
    console.log('Click me #2');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__button" data-button="1">Click me #1</div>
  <div class="block__button" data-button="2">Click me #2</div>
  <div class="block__button" data-button="3">Click me #3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="button">Кнопка 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="button">Кнопка 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="button">Кнопка 3</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('button')) {
        console.log('123');
    }
});
```

у метода closest слабая [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#search=closest)!!